# Generate a PDF file from a HTML file using PHP

Tags: php, html, fpdf

I am trying to generate a PDF from an HTML page using PHP. I am using fpdf library to convert HTML to pdf. But the code is not working properly. Can anyone please help me to find out the error of my code?

```
<?php

require('fpdf.php');

if (isset($_POST['signup'])) {

    $pdf=new FPDF();
    $pdf->AddPage();
    $fp = fopen("index.html","r");
    $strContent = fread($fp, filesize("index.html"));
    fclose($fp);
    $pdf->WriteHTML($strContent);
    $pdf->Output();
}
?>
```

This is the PHP code I am trying.

Comment: And "is not working properly" means what _exactly_ ? Or are we meant to _guess_ ?

Comment: *"But the code is not working properly. Can anyone please help me to find out the error of my code?"* Welcome on stackoverflow your current question is not really clear i suggest you to read this -> https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask .. Also do you get a error or a white page only?

Comment: Sorry for my explanation problems. "is not working properly" means it generates a PDF but the browser is saying that  "we can't open this file".

Comment: Can you open it with any other PDF reader?

Comment: `$strContent` can be replaced with `file_get_contents('index.html')`, make sure that you actually read file. Have you tried to pass non-default values to `output()`?

Comment: no I can't. I already tried it.

Comment: Make sure you have proper PHP error reporting configured, and then check what the downloaded file contains, by opening it in a text or hex editor. See if you find any error messages in there.

Comment: FPDF has no `WriteHTML()` method. This code should trigger a fatal error.